# how to detect current project using a library in nx monorepository

Tags: reactjs, react-native, monorepo, nx-monorepo

I have an NX mono-repository including three apps(2 react websites and 1 mobile application) and some shared libraries. How can I detect which application I am in, in one of the shared libraries codes?